# Tabulator 4.9, is there a way to have 2 different colors of text within a cell?

Tags: tabulator

The requirements from the customer state that a record's `Comment` and `Description` fields must be displayed in the same cell but the text of the `Comment` must be displayed in red while the `Description` should be black.  Using a mutator, I can combine the 2 fields and display them in one cell, but I haven't seen how to make one have red text and the other black text within that cell.

Is there a way?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldnt bother doing that, just use a [Customer Formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/format#format-custom) function

```js
formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
    return '<span style=color:red>' + cell.getRow().getData().Comment + '</span><P><span style=color:black>' + cell.getRow().getData().Description + '</span></p>';
}
```

Comment: This works great.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Michael, your response helped my achieve the text colors I was seeking.  Unfortunately, the comment and description are both multiline outputs.  I previously used a custom mutator because doing so allowed me to apply the `textarea` format.  I used the custom formatter above and then used the `variableHeight:true` property as was suggested in the documentation, but it was ineffectual.  Can you think of a way I can format the text color and have the cell handle multiline data?  Thanks.

Comment: You prolly want to add replaceAll('\n','<BR>') to the end of your Comment and Description fields in the formatter .... https://jsfiddle.net/rdomfv7c/